# function shows an error

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to use a function and i am getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) on line 3
```

attached the code

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'zkr_my_theme_menu_first'); // we need this action to create     the menu
// this  makes the menu
function zkr_my_theme_menu_first()
{
$page_title = "Theme Settings";
$menu_title = "Theme Settings";
$capability = "administrator";
$menu_slug = "zkr-theme-settings";
$function = "zkr_main_theme_menu";
$icon_url = get_template_directory_uri() . "/zkrframework/images/settings_icon.gif";

add_menu_page($page_title,$menu_title,$capability,$menu_slug, $function, $icon_url);

}
// this shows the menu html think of it as the view.
function zkr_main_theme_menu() 
{
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
if ( !user_can( $user_id, 'create_users' ) )
    return false;
?>

<div class="wrap">

<h2>Hello Menu</h2>

</div>

<?php
}

?>
```

I am trying to add a menu to my wordpress admin panel and i am getting this error

How can i Fix this Error ?

Comment: In this moment i test your code and the result was OK. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function addAction() on line 3 but you haven't declared it in the code sample you provide.

It's OK to call a function before you declare it but interpreter shrugs its shoulders in a metaphorical 'wtf' when calling an undefined function.

Comment: add_action is a built-in Wordpress function.